# I cannot see the contents of a memory

Tags: memory, verilog, simulation, instantiation, icarus

I have a problem when I try to simulate a circuit which is supposed to process data taken from an SRAM memory. Firstly, an SRAM memory is filled with data, this could be seen if one has a look over the last testbench, than, the stored data will be processed by an automaton. Then, the output, in some specific situations, is stored in another SRAM memory. Thus, when simulated, the circuit behaves in a strange way, because the rd_data_instrucions, which represents read data from the first SRAM memory, is always undefined. Consequently, all other signals depending on rd_data_instructions are undefined too. The code is posted here.

P.S.: Modules sram_1port_instructions and sram_1port_data should behave as clocked SRAMs, having a write enable signal so that when wr_en is high, the memory stores data received(wr_data) and when wr_en is low, the memory could output data (rd_data).
Module user represents an "interface" which facilitates the writing process so that writing in the SRAM instruction memory does not require the address to which data is stored because this module provides a mechanism which increments the "write-address-pointer" of the memory. Further, we can see the corresponding testbench for this module. Then, we can see the corresponding module of another memory, which is created for output storage, and a module designed to facilitate the reading process (i.e. something similar to the previous situation, but, instead of facilitating the writing process, it eases reading).
Last, but not least, we may distinguish a wishbone module, which is supposed to interconnect all the previous modules in order to create a digital system. Consequently, an automaton takes data from the SRAM instruction memory, then outputs some data which is stored in another memory. Finally, the outcome could be read from the SRAM data memory.
The problem occurs when I try to simulate the system because I encounter difficulties when trying to read some signals, e.g. rd_data_instructions, which should display the previously stored values from the SRAM instruction memory, implicitly the "in" signal, which should provide the input for the automaton, and so on. Within the wishbone module, I used a special signal labelled "start" which sets the write-enable on 0 so that the SRAM memory is prepared for the reading process. This special signal actually triggers the automaton, by "feeding" it with input data from the memory.

```
//wishbone module
module wishbone(
    input clk,rst,start,
    output reg [2:0]in,
    output reg wr_en_instructions,wr_en_display,
    input [2:0] wr_data_instructions,//created for usr, in order to make possible to write data
    output reg [3:0] wr_data_display,
    output [2:0] rd_data_instructions,
    output [3:0] rd_data_display,//created for user, in order to make possible the display
    output [12:0]o
);

reg [15:0] pointer_instructions,pointer_display;

initial wr_en_instructions = 1'b1;

control_unit i0(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.in(in),.o(o));
user i1(.clk(clk),.wr_en(wr_en),.address_in(pointer_instructions),.wr_data(wr_data_instructions),.rd_data(rd_data_instructions));
display i2(.clk(clk),.wr_en(wr_en_display),.address_in(pointer_display),.wr_data(wr_data_display),.rd_data(rd_data_display));
integer i = 0;
always @ * begin
    wr_en_display = ~wr_en_instructions;
end
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(start) begin
        pointer_instructions <= 16'b0;
        pointer_display <= 16'b0;
        wr_en_instructions <= 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
        $display(rd_data_instructions);
        if(!wr_en_instructions) begin
            if(rd_data_instructions == 3'b1xx) begin
                wr_en_instructions <= 1'b1;//???
            end
            else if(rd_data_instructions == 3'b010) begin
                in <= rd_data_instructions;
                wr_data_display <= o;
                pointer_instructions <= pointer_instructions + 1;
                pointer_display <= pointer_display + 1;
            end
            else begin
                in <= rd_data_instructions;
                pointer_instructions <= pointer_instructions + 1;
            end
        end
        else begin
            i = i + 1;
        end
    end
end

endmodule

//testbench for top module
module wishbone_tb(
    output reg clk,rst,start,
    output [2:0]in,
    output wr_en_instructions,wr_en_display,
    output reg [2:0] wr_data_instructions,//created for usr, in order to make possible to write data
    output [3:0] wr_data_display,
    output [2:0] rd_data_instructions,
    output [3:0] rd_data_display,//created for user, in order to make possible the display
    output [12:0]o
);

wishbone cut(
    .clk(clk),.rst(rst),.start(start),
    .in(in),
    .wr_en_instructions(wr_en_instructions),.wr_en_display(wr_en_display),
    .wr_data_instructions(wr_data_instructions),
    .wr_data_display(wr_data_display),
    .rd_data_instructions(rd_data_instructions),
    .rd_data_display(rd_data_display),
    .o(o)
);

initial $dumpvars(0,wishbone_tb);

initial begin
    clk = 1'd1;
    repeat (600000)
    #100 clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin
    rst = 1'b1;
    #400 rst = 1'b0;
end

initial begin
    start = 1'b0;
    #13000400 start = 1'b1;
    #400 start = 1'b0;
end

initial begin
    wr_data_instructions = 3'd1;
    #3000400 wr_data_instructions = 3'd2;
    #1000000 wr_data_instructions = 3'd1;
    #3000000 wr_data_instructions = 3'd0;
    #2000000 wr_data_instructions = 3'd3;
    #1000000 wr_data_instructions = 3'd1;
    #3000000 wr_data_instructions = 3'd4;//halt
end

endmodule
```

Comment: `rd_data_instructions == 3'b1xx` -- it behaves the same way as `rd_data_instructions == 3'b100`. I guess, you meant the `==?` operator.

Comment: Indeed, that was a bug, but the problem still persists.